# Button Visible When Supposed to be Hidden

Tags: jquery, ajax

When hitting button should hide rest button will display.  Initilally button only display rest will hide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        LoadData();
        $("#Submit").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Proceedtopay")',
                data: '{fv: ' + JSON.stringify(fv) + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                   // alert("Data has been added successfully.");
                    // LoadData();
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('clicked')) {
                        //func(some, other, parameters);
                        $("#Submit").hide();
                        $("#Submit1").show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $this.data('clicked', true);
                        //func(some, parameter);
                        $("#Submit").show();
                        $("#Submit1").hide();
                    }



                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while submiting data");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function LoadData() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Submit").show();
            $("#Submit1").hide();

        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your expectation of:

```
success: function () {
    var $this = $(this); // what is $this supposed to be
```

Since there was no `context` parameter was provided, $this is not reference to an element. Since it's not finding the correct element, it can't find the clicked attribute correctly, so it's probably always hitting the else.